# How can I create a view with information about the next or previous record?

Tags: sql-server, create-view

Can someone help me with the "create view" code to get the result sets below.

CREATE VIEW MyView AS (SELECT .....FROM Movements ...)

I have a table "Movements" like this:

```
 
ID  name    City        from date
U1  Smith   New York    1 jan 2000
U1  Smith   Austin      1 dec 2001
U1  Smith   Scottsdale  1 jul 2002
U2  Jack    Houston     1 sep 2000
U2  Jack    New York    1 nov 2000
U3  Jane    Knoxville   1 feb 2000
U3  Jane    Richmond    1 mrt 2001
U3  Jane    San Diego   1 jan 2002
U3  Jane    Oak Park    1 oct 2004
```

I would like to make a view of the movements of the persons.

I may have 2 result sets. The first one has a columnnumber limit, I know.

I like to have a view for each result set

**Resultset 1:**

```
ID  name    city 1      city 2    city 3      city 4
U1  Smith   New York    Austin    Scottsdale    
U2  Jack    Houton      New York        
U3  Jane    Knoxville   Richmond  San Diego   Oak Park
```

Or

**Resultset2**

```
ID  name    City        from date   to city
U1  Smith   New York    1 jan 2000  Austin
U1  Smith   Austin      1 dec 2001  Scottsdale
U1  Smith   Scottsdale  1 jul 2002  
U2  Jack    Houston     1 sep 2000  New York
U2  Jack    New York    1 nov 2000  
U3  Jane    Knoxville   1 feb 2000  Richmond
U3  Jane    Richmond    1 mrt 2001  San Diego
U3  Jane    San Diego   1 jan 2002  Oak Park
U3  Jane    Oak Park    1 oct 2004
```

Comment: _"I would like to make a view"_ and _"I may have 2 result sets"_ does not compute. _"The first one has a columnnumber limit, I know."_ What limit? Why?

Comment: This question shows no research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `LEAD` window function for resultset 2

```
SELECT ID,
       NAME,
       City,
       [from date],
       toCity = Coalesce(Lead(City)over(Partition by ID, name order by [from date]),'')
FROM   Yourtable
```

Resultset 1 requires `dynamic pivot`

```
DECLARE @sql      NVARCHAR(max),
        @col_list VARCHAR(max)

SET @col_list =Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ','+ Quotename('City '+ Cast(Row_number()OVER(partition BY ID ORDER BY [from date]) AS VARCHAR(50)))
                      FROM   Yourtable
                      FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
SET @sql = '
select * 
    from (select ID,name,City,city_num =''City ''+ cast(row_number()over(partition by ID order by [from date]) as varchar(50))  
            from Yourtable) a
    pivot (max(city) for city_num in ('+ @col_list + ')) pv'

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```